# Telerik MVC 3 Chart Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a requirement that I have to have some text on a page and when the user hovers over the text a line chart is shown in a tooltip. It works ok in IE 8 and Firefox but in IE 9 I only see a blank graph, no lines. I have verified that the line chart works in IE 9 when it is displayed on just a normal page (no ajax / tooltip).

Here is my javascript to create the tooltip when hovered over:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/LineChart",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify({ lines: linesData, categories: categoriesData }),
    success: function (data) {

        tooltipContent.append(data);

        $that.tooltip({
            top: 0,
            left: 25,
            staysOpen: false,
            bodyHandler: function () {
                return tooltipContent.html();
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Again, this work ok in IE 8 and Firefox.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not using the template feature of the tooltip and define it that way? You can get access to the original data item (including fields that are currently not being used by the chart) responsible for each point of the Chart by just using dataItem.FieldName in the template string. For more information: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-chart-tooltip.html